# Help define the Bill Of Materials for a blog contest

Tags: discussion, blog

I suggested this in chat

> "We should start a series of challenge questions on the site. give a
>   list of random materials, and see what people can make with them.".

And @Aarthi Devanathan Ψ suggested we do it on the blog , and also offered to help fund a prize.  So all we need now is a list of random materials. I figured I would ask here on meta for suggestions, and let the community vote for the junk that will be used.  I'm thinking top 3-4 items will be good.

So to make this work, please enter one *thing* (2x4, bucket, coffee can, duct tape, whatever) per answer and up-vote the ones you like.

In about two weeks (or whenever we secure a prize) I'll post a blog entry defining the challenge, and I'll use the top voted items from this question as the *Bill Of Materials*.

Comment: We also need to define: How long the contest will run (start Date, End Date), how entries will be submitted, and the best way to choose a winner.

Comment: How broadly can we define "materials"?

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, something to have fun with.  I like it!

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo I was sort of thinking it should be like a recycle type of thing, so things that are "garbage" (coffee cans, milk jugs, etc) would be good.  But basically anything that is legal, easily obtained, and relatively cheap would be great.

Comment: Cool.  Any limit on # of answers per user?

Comment: @theevilgreebo nope, answer as many times as you like, the items will be selected based on votes.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to post practical, actual DIY problems? maybe ones you solved yourself, but are looking for different alternatives?

Comment: @JeffAtwood I think it might be more fun to leave it open, and see what types of contraptions people can build.  I wouldn't want it to turn into a "How can you jerry-rig *this* using only these things". The site is about doing things right and building within codes, so I don't think we should reward people for hacked solutions.

Comment: the underlying goal of this "challenge", is to show people that stuff they would normally toss in the trash can be repurposed and become useful again.

Comment: I'm not sure doing a nonsense Rub Goldberg contest is really in the spirit of home improvement. it may be fun, but how does this help promote serious use of this site?

Comment: I have been away from the site for the last month or so renovating two houses at once, bit stressed, but would like to think about this a bit. Leaning towards challenging folks to create realistic solutions to common projects. maybe put out a list of materials and ask what they were used to create? Lots of smart folks on this site, I bet we can come up with something fun and informative at the same time.

Comment: @shirlockhomes As I mentioned, the spirit of the challenge would be to reduce waste and reuse non standard items in an interesting way.  I agree the idea could use a bit more polishing, maybe we could all discuss it more during the project update chat on Thursday.

Answer (score 1):

Milk Crate

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Duct tape:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A single 8' stick of 3/4" CPVC

Comment: All we need is a funnel, and we could make super long beer bongs.

Comment: makes a great bottle rocket launcher when cut into 12" pieces and mounted into a 2X8

Answer (score 0):

Six pennies

[image]

Comment: Do they have to be American pennies?

Answer (score 0):

Door hinge:

[image]

Comment: Does that include hardware (screws), or just the hinge?

Comment: Hmm, I think we should include the 6 screws, but at least 3 have to be used on the hinge. Thoughts?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe projects could include other materials, but had to "feature" the selected items. So, in that case it would't matter either way.  Bonus points for people that use *only* the selected items. Still need help defining the challenge, so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Well, if duct tape is included, I'm having a hard time thinking of things you couldn't make. :)